# I made a timer program that counts number

Tags: python

I made a timer program.
The code below is the program I wrote.

```
from time import sleep

y=float(input("How many seconds should I count?  "))

while (y>0.1):
          sleep(0.1)
          y=y-0.1
          print( "{:.1f} second(s)".format(y) )
print("Boooooooooooooooooooooooooooom!")
```

But,  I want to make it more perfect by creating a program that satisfies the conditions below. Can you give me some advice?

I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
from time import sleep

y = input("How many seconds should I count?  ")
if y.count(".") > 1:
    print("Error: Your input contains '.' " + str(y.count(".")) + " times")
else:
    try:
        value = float(y)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Your input is a string")
    else:
        if value < 0:
            print("Error: Your input is less than zero")
        else:
            while (y>0.1):
                sleep(0.1)
                y=y-0.1
                print( "{:.1f} second(s)".format(y) )
            print("Boooooooooooooooooooooooooooom!")
```

I have added in check of negative number, string and two or more "."(s) in the input.

You can add more like these using if, elif and else statements.

Hoping this code worked as you wanted!!